# Custom header fields in AngularJS $http DELETE

Tags: angularjs, rest, http

I am attempting the following to add custom headers via Angular's $http:

```
return $http({
  url: 'api/post/:postId',
  method: "delete",
  headers: {
    'my_param': my_param_value
  },
}).then(function(response) {
  return response.data;
});
```

But 'my_param' is not added the the headers. Is that because of the DELETE method? I have read many of the SO posts about this and just can't seem to find a way to include `my_param` with DELETE in a single step. Adding it to the body doesn't work as many people have mentioned. I need this extra parameter to do a server-side task after delete.

Using Chrome for dev but this is a mobile app. Preflight works fine - this isn't a CORS issue.

Comment: How are you validating that it isn't added? Provide more troubleshooting details as to what has been done

Comment: @charlietfl It's not shown in Chrome dev tools in request headers, and not on server.`Yii::$app->request->getHeaders()` outputs the headers and it's not there.

Comment: What is in the `my_param` variable? Because if it's undefined it will be removed.

Comment: Doesn't matter what I put in `my_param` - it's removed. I checked Safari also.